# match() or split() messing up my code

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming, I'm learning javascript. I don't understand what's wrong with my code but I'm unable to reach the result (i.e. show the total seconds in the text box). The program works fine until matching the pattern. But it's getting all messed up when I'm using the split() function. Please tell me where I'm going wrong. Thank You

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function cal() {
      var text = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML;
      var pattern = text.match(/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/);
      var b = pattern.split(':');

      var seconds = (+b[0]) * 3600 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]);
      document.getElementById("tot").value = seconds;

    }
  </script>
  <div>
    <p id="pp">The Time Right Now Is 12:34:56</p>
    Total Seconds: <input type=t ext id="tot"><button onclick="cal()"> Click Here!</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: pattern.split is not a function"  Array does not have split method. `console.log(pattern)`

Comment: [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array, not a string, and arrays don't have a `split` function.

Comment: Press [F12] to open the developer console. Run your code. The error message reads "TypeError: pattern.split is not a function ... lineno: 16" - now you put a `console.log(pattern);` before that line. It prints `Array [  "01:02:03" ]`. Now you check the documentation and see that an array doesn't have a `split` method, but a `string` has. The string is the first array element, you access it via `pattern[0].split(...)` or `var [pattern] = text.match(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You can check the console (F12 in Chrome) to see if any errors occur. You can also step through the code to see what's going on by adding a `debugger;` statement there somewhere.

If you move the JavaScript code to a separate file, you can also write tests (for example with Jasmine) to automate testing your code.

All that being said, the following error is displayed in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: pattern.split is not a function
```

The fix:

```
var b = pattern[0].split(':');
```

But once you've started with a Regex, you can continue that way. The following will group the hours, minutes and seconds

```
var result = "12:34:56".match(/([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/)
var hours = result[1];
var minutes = result[2];
var seconds = result[3];
```

Better yet, for date parsing like what you are doing here, you could use a library that offers this sort of things out of the box. [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is a very popular one. If this is the only thing you do, using a library is overkill but if you are doing alot of date parsing/formatting, then it will make things much easier for you.

```
# Install on command line with npm (you can also use bower, ...)
npm install moment

// import and use
import * as moment from "moment";
var parsed = moment("12:34:56", "HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) method, and [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array.

**The problem:** 
You can not applay `.split` on the returned value from `.match

**Solution:** 
You need to use array index `[0]` to match the first element from returned array.

**Your code after fixing**

```js
function cal() {
  var text = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML;
  var pattern = text.match(/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/);
  var b = pattern[0].split(':');
  var seconds = (+b[0]) * 3600 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]);
  document.getElementById("tot").value = seconds;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="pp">The Time Right Now Is 12:34:56</p>
  Total Seconds: <input type=t ext id="tot">
  <button onclick="cal()"> Click Here!</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern return as  list. use `conditional statement`

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function cal() {
      var text = document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML;
      var pattern = text.match(/[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/);
      b = pattern[0].split(':'); 
      console.log(b)

      var seconds = (b[0]) * 3600 + (b[1]) * 60 + (b[2]);
      document.getElementById("tot").value = seconds;

    }
  </script>
  <div>
    <p id="pp">The Time Right Now Is 12:34:56</p>
    Total Seconds: <input type=t ext id="tot"><button onclick="cal()"> Click Here!</button>
  </div>
</body>
```